# wireless doesn't work

Tags: wireless, atheros

I have installed Ubuntu 11.04 on my Acer Aspire 4349 with AR9485 wireless network adapter. The wired connection works fine, but I can't connect to wireless. The enable wireless tab is not listed on the network manager. Please help me with this.
Thank you.

I ran the following command.

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
07:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev ff)

sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet
   vendor: Atheros Communications
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: c1
   serial: 04:7d:7b:4e:59:6c
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.0-NAPI firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:41 memory:93400000-9343ffff ioport:3000(size=128)

lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
ppp_deflate            12838  0 
zlib_deflate           26594  1 ppp_deflate
bsd_comp               12777  0 
ppp_async              17308  1 
crc_ccitt              12595  1 ppp_async
option                 21045  2 
usb_wwan               19711  1 option
usbserial              37116  7 option,usb_wwan
parport_pc             32111  0 
ppdev                  12849  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     27479  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   255820  1 
binfmt_misc            13213  1 
joydev                 17322  0 
ath9k                 103633  0 
snd_hda_intel          24140  4 
snd_hda_codec          90901  3  snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13274  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                80244  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25269  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                51291  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
sparse_keymap          13666  0 
i915                  450944  3 
mac80211              257001  1 ath9k
snd_timer              28659  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14110  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
uvcvideo               66851  0 
ath9k_common           13611  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              300328  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
ath                    19141  2 ath9k,ath9k_hw
videodev               75143  1 uvcvideo
drm_kms_helper         40745  1 i915
cfg80211              156212  3 ath9k,mac80211,ath
snd                    55295  17 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
psmouse                73312  0 
drm                   180037  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
soundcore              12600  1 snd
serio_raw              12990  0 
snd_page_alloc         14073  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
i2c_algo_bit           13184  1 i915
video                  18951  1 i915
lp                     13349  0 
parport                36746  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
usbhid                 41704  0 
hid                    77084  1 usbhid
usb_storage            43946  0 
uas                    17676  0 
ahci                   21591  3 
libahci                25548  1 ahci
atl1c                  36237  0
```

No result for rfkill list all.

Comment: post result of `lspci`, `sudo lshw -c network`, `lsmod` and `rfkill list all`

Answer (score 0):

`sudo rfkill unblock all` to unblock all wireless adapters. (try it)

And you might want to check this: http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=17833

Comment: I've tried, didn't work.

Comment: Tried what the link said?